# Is this possible to find modulo of different value and get same result?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible, for $a,b,m,n,x,y\in\mathbb N$ to have

$$x = y^a \pmod n \qquad \text{ and }\qquad  y = x^b \pmod m ?$$

**For example:** $17=5^{11} \pmod{21}$ and $5=17^{11} \pmod{21}$ is an integer but i want to use different value of modulo in both equation instead of using $21$.

Comment: You mean like $2 = 3^2 \bmod 7$ and $3 = 2^3 \bmod 5$? Sure it's possible

Comment: yes but how can u explain it?

Comment: $2$ is a primitve root modulo $5$ and $3$ is a primitive root modulo $7$ so we were guaranteed to find something...

Comment: Do you want $a=b$ in your statement? At least $a=b=11$ in the example.

Comment: no not necessary that a=b.

Comment: @Cocopuffs In general formula or method for large 100 bit numbers.

Comment: @Aria I don't think this gives a formula, sorry. As to the method, for any modulus $n$ that has a primitive root, there are $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ such, so you have a number of choices. As far as I know there is no closed-form way of finding any of them, but usually $2$, $3$, $5$, something small will work.

Comment: @Cocopuffs what is the benefit of taking primitive root ?

Comment: @Aria For example, in the case of mod $7$, $3$ being a primitive root guarantees that we can solve $2 = 3^a \mod 7$ for some $a$

Comment: @Cocopuffs thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Take any two powers $y^a$ and $x^b$. Then let $n$ be any divisor of $y^a-x$ and $m$ be any divisor of $x^b-y$.

For instance, consider $y^a=3^5$ and $x^b=7^{11}$. Now factor $3^5-7$ and $7^{11}-3$:
$$3^5-7=2^2 \cdot 59, \text{ and } 7^{11}-3=2^2 \cdot 5\cdot 98866337.$$ 
Then, for example, you can take $n=59$, and $m=98866337$.

Comment: how do u find the value of $n$=59 and $m$=98866337.

Comment: By factoring $y^a-x$ and $x^b-y$. I updated the answer.

Comment: Is it possible if we only know the value of x,n,a? i mean we have all parameter of first equation except y and have to calculate y by help of x,a,n and then value of m.